# T SQL Nested IF...ELSE in BEGIN...END

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I would like some guidance on why there are issues with this procedure. I seem to get an error that states "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'."

I've added comments where I think the issues are. labeled (x) and (y) in the in-code-comments. I used DataGrip for syntax highlighting and that's how I know these pairings exist. But I still don't understand why.

I am aware that a `CASE` statement could solve this issue. But I would like to know why it is not working with `IF...ELSE`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AuthenticateUser(
  @UserName NVARCHAR(50),
  @Password NVARCHAR(50),
  @Result INT OUTPUT
) AS
  BEGIN -- Cannot find a corresponding END
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @userID INT

    IF exists(SELECT UserID FROM Users WHERE UserName = @UserName)
      BEGIN -- paired with END (y)
        SET @userID = (SELECT UserID FROM Users WHERE UserName = @UserName AND Password = dbo.EncryptPassword(@Password, Salt))

        IF @userID IS NULL -- Paired with END (x)
          SET @Result = 0
        ELSE
          SET @Result = 1

      END -- paired with IF (x)
    ELSE
      SET @Result = 0

  END -- paired with BEGIN (y)
GO
```

Comment: Can't replicate issue in SQL Server 2012 with SSMS 2016 or SSMS 2012. What version are you using?
Do you have any other code in the query?

Comment: Are you running this code from somewhere else than SSMS? Go is not a SQL command, but a separator in SSMS

Comment: Hey, your procedure is working fine. I tried this on SQL Server 2014.

Comment: This might be the real problem, but I'm using SQL Server for Linux. (Hence why I'm using Datagrip and not SSMS)

Comment: @Edwinj how are you running 2008/2012 on Linux? I thought that was only supported since 2016

Answer (score 1):

How about try adding a BEGIN  and END label on each IF ELSE condition. Something like this.

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE AuthenticateUser
            (
              @UserName NVARCHAR(50) ,
              @Password NVARCHAR(50) ,
              @Result INT OUTPUT
            )
        AS
            BEGIN -- Cannot find a corresponding END
                SET NOCOUNT ON

                DECLARE @userID INT

                IF EXISTS ( SELECT  1
                            FROM    Users
                            WHERE   UserName = @UserName )
                    BEGIN -- paired with END (y)
                        SET @userID = ( SELECT  UserID
                                        FROM    Users
                                        WHERE   UserName = @UserName
                                                AND Password = dbo.EncryptPassword(@Password,
                                                          Salt)
                                      )
                        IF @userID IS NULL -- Paired with END (x)
                            BEGIN
                                SET @Result = 0
                            END
                        ELSE
                            BEGIN
                                SET @Result = 1
                            END
                    END -- paired with IF (x)
                ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        SET @Result = 0
                    END 
            END -- paired with BEGIN (y)
        GO
```

Comment: Thanks @von, but this unfortunately did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

@Edwinj

Nothing wrong in If else block , there is issue in your code

**Salt** (Password = dbo.EncryptPassword(@Password, **Salt**)))

**Salt** is neither it Number  not veritable or string so function EncryptPassword will fail with error.

Comment: The code isn't actually running at this point, it's just a Stored Proc definition, so it shouldn't make any difference what's being passed to Encrypt Password

Comment: it is not a  legal variable nor int not a legal  string.

Comment: How do you know it's not a column in the `users` table?

Comment: dude you are calling function EncryptPassword signature used  tells that it takes 2 parm  second parm is Salt which is neither veritable not int or string....

Comment: In the absence of definitions of EncryptPassword (it's not a built in function on MY copy of SQL 2012), and the `Users` table, you can't possibly know if he's using it correctly or not. It's obvious that it's not a variable, an int literal or a string literal. I suspect that `Salt` is a column from the `Users` table, so it's being called like this: `Select ... From Users Where ... AND Password = dbo.EncryptPassword(@Password, Users.Salt)`

Comment: Also, that's something that SSMS would certainly pick up on before it even got to this stage and it would be a trivial thing to fix, not something to ask SO about